# Why do we need static methods in interfaces Java 8?

Tags: java, interface, static, java-8

Why? Isn't this kind of anti-pattern?

Comment: I've never used them, which proves that we dont "need" (i.e. require) them.

Comment: They make perfect sense to me. Imagine `Arrays.asList(T...)` being a more reasonably named `List.create(T...)`, for instance. But this question is OT for SO, since it's an opinion-based question.

Comment: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/233053/why-were-default-and-static-methods-added-to-interfaces-in-java-8-when-we-alread

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> This makes it easier for you to organize helper methods in your libraries; you can keep static methods specific to an interface in the same interface rather than in a separate class.

Please read [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/defaultmethods.html)